# Already joined conference is not accessible smack 4.1.7

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack, asmack

Am developing an Android app which makes use of XMPP (Smack 4.1.7) to implement the chat feature. While implementing Multi User Chat am able to send invitation and invite users and start chatting with the group and it works fine until i close the app.

When i relaunch the app and try sending a message to the same group, am getting an error message as,

**Conference room does not exist** or **Only occupants are allowed to send messages to the conference**

Am pretty sure am sending to the same JID (groupname@conference.serveraddress).

Has anyone faced the same issue? Should i add any extra parameter to configure this feature in server / client side?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How do you send the message?

Comment: MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            MultiUserChat chat = manager.getMultiUserChat(groupName + "@conference." + serverAddress);
            chat.sendMessage(message);

Comment: I assume your connection gets terminated without stream management being active when your activity gets into background, thus you need to rejoin the room, which you don't do.

Comment: Actually when i relaunch my app after joining the room and request for the list of rooms i have joined it returns null list. I assume some setting should be turned on to save all these values in server side. Am still searching what setting is that.